# Joomla: get rid of message "The browser you are using is out of date"

Tags: joomla2.5

Today, I'm getting this message in IE11, Chrome and FF of my website:

> The browser you are using is out of date. You will not see all the
>   features of our website. Please upgrade to one of these browsers: 
>   Google Chrome  Mozilla Firefox  Internet Explorer

Which besides being irritating is also erroneous (my browsers are updated).
I'm using Joomla 2.5.28 and my template is Base3 (JoomlaBamboo).

I tried checking all modules, plugins and template settings to find out if there was something like this message enabled but couldn't find out anything.

Help anyone?

Comment: I am guessing but this could be a template setting. Check if you have anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your template, as the browser detection script clearly needs an update.